# How to use C# callback functions having interfaces as parameters in a static class?

Tags: c#, class, interface, static, callback

I have to adapt several functions in an open source C# wrapper (tao.sdl) for a C library (sld) in order to support a specific hardware. In this wrapper, all C functions have been encapsulated in a static class.

Unfortunately, two callback functions in the C# lib giving access to the specific hardware mentioned before require as parameter a class that implements two interfaces. This one must therefore be non-static … and, as far as I know, the corresponding instance cannot be referenced in the first lib…

How could I catch events from the device (via the available callbacks) and use them in the modified C# wrapper class ? This one must stay static as modifications must be transparent for clients’ applications?

Here is the interface and the callback definitions:

```
public interface IDataHandler
{
   void HandleHidData(bytes[]);
}

public void SetDataCallback(IDataHandler handler)
```

Please consider I’m newbie in C#, so there might be a trivial answer to my question, but I wasn’t able to find it by myself or on the Web…

Thanks a lot for you help !

PS: As requested, you'll find below a (as short as possible) summary of the issue.

```
namespace Sample
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Methods definitions giving access to the new device 
    // Sources of this DLL are NOT provided.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public partial class NewDeviceLib
    {
        // ...

        public interface IFirstInterface
        {
            void HandleData(byte[] data);
        }
        public static NewDeviceLib GetDevice ();
        public void SetDataCallback(IFirstInterface handler);

        // ...
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Custom class implementing IFirstInterface
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class NewDeviceHandler: NewDeviceLib.IFirstInterface
    {
        // Storage of collected data to be processed
        List<byte[]> m_data = new List<byte[]>();

        // This callback is triggered each time device state changes
        public void HandleData (byte[] data)
        {
            // Stores data for future use in C# wrapper
            m_data.Add(data);
        }

        public List<byte[]> GetPendingData ()
        {
            return m_data;
        }

        // Clear processed data
        public void ClearPendingData()
        {
            m_data.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Open source lib to be modified in order to support the new device
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public struct Event
    {
        // public structures defining the events
        public int type;
        public byte[] data;
        // ...
    }

    // HYPOTHETICAL NON static implementation of open source lib
    // to be adapted to support new device type
    public class OpenSourceLibWrapperClass
    {
        // ....

        // adds device ref to support new device
        NewDeviceLib m_device = null;

        // adds instance of NewDeviceLib (this must be non static) 
        NewDeviceHandler m_newDeviceHandler;

        // Initialization of all connected devices
        private void InitNewDevice ()
        {
            // added to support new device type
            m_device = NewDeviceLib.GetDevice();
            if (m_device != null)
            {
                m_device.SetDataCallback(m_newDeviceHandler);
            }
        }

        // Existing method wrapping C function library
        [DllImport("DLL_NAME", EntryPoint = "_Init")]
        private static extern void _Init();
        public void Init ()
        {
            // added to initialize new device
            InitNewDevice();
            // calls external C function for other devices
            _Init();
        }

        // Existing method wrapping C function library
        // returns 0 when all pending events have been processed
        [DllImport("DLL_NAME", EntryPoint = "_PollEvent")]
        private static extern int _PollEvent(out Event DevEvent);
        public int PollEvent(out Event DevEvent)
        {
            // Added to support new device
            if (m_device != null)
            {
                if (m_newDeviceHandler.GetPendingData().Count > 0)
                {
                    DevEvent = new Event();
                    DevEvent.type = 9999;
                    DevEvent.data = m_newDeviceHandler.GetPendingData()[0];
                    m_newDeviceHandler.ClearPendingData();
                    return m_newDeviceHandler.GetPendingData().Count;
                }
            }

            // usual process for events of other devices
            return _PollEvent(out DevEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

I should I proceed as class OpenSourceWrapperClass must stay static ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What code are you trying to write?

Comment: I've adapted my post to include a more detailed sample.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your static class with a non-static class that implements the required interfaces, like this (you've presented only one interface, so only one in this example):

```
class SldDataHandler : IDataHandler
{
    public void HandleHidData(byte[] bytes)
    {
        //use static class here
    }
}
```

And use it like this for example:

```
SetDataCallback(new SldDataHandler());
```